# Hadoop Data extraction aftermath

Tags: hadoop2

What are the ways to ship the extracted data after MapReduce in a Hadoop system?  I mean the data is extracted by employing say Pig Latin, then how the data would be sent out to another application say a reporting application to make use of it by the group interested in it?  What are the specific tools to ship out the user friendly data from Hadoop?

I know this question of mine don't have any research value, but I feel it worth to learn the aftermath process.